# XSLT select an element with text containing number in format "1.1.1"

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to check if the element el contains text with format 1.1.1. How to identify this el element?

```
<root>
  <story>
    <el>1.1.1 <b>head1</b></el>
    <el>some text</el>
    <el>1.1.1 <b>head1</b></el>
    <el>some text</el>
    <el>1.10.2<b>head1</b></el>
    <el>some text</el>
    <el>19.9.10<b>head1</b></el>
 </story>
</root>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Well, I expect the following result:

```
<root>
  <story>
    <h3>1.1.1 head1</h3>
    <el>some text</el>
    <h3>1.1.1 head1</h3>
    <el>some text</el>
    <h3>1.10.2 head1</h3>
    <el>some text</el>
    <h3>19.9.10 head1</h3>
  </story>
</root>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There are several methods that will work.

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't.

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? Version 1 and version 2 will potentially have different answers?

Comment: here I'm using xslt 1

Comment: Looking at your input and output, it looks like you can achieve what you require simply by checking for `el` elements which have a child `b` element. Will you ever have the case where an `el` element has text in `1.1.1` format, but no child `b`? Thanks.

Comment: no, some text in tag b always exists in el element along with numbers in this format.

Comment: And can you get `el` elements with `b` elements but no text in `1.1.1` format? If so, what should happen to these?

Comment: they should stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should have tried something. In issues like this, where you only transform a portion of the XML (in your case, changing `el` into `h3` and removing `b`) you should immediately think "Aha! Identity Transform" (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). This means starting off with this template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you are half-way there! You then only need to write templates to change the nodes you do need (which should take priority over the generic identity template).

Now, as you are using XSLT 1.0, there is not a convenient way to identity a "number" in the format 1.1.1. If you want to delight in confusing expressions, here is one way of matching your `el` elements, that then replaces then with an `h3` element.

```
<xsl:template match="el[normalize-space(concat('[', translate(translate(normalize-space(text()), ' ', '_'), '1234567890', '          '), ']')) = '[ . . ]']">
    <h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </h3>
</xsl:template>
```

You would have a similar one for matching, and then removing, the `b` element underneath the `el`

```
<xsl:template match="el[normalize-space(concat('[', translate(translate(normalize-space(text()), ' ', '_'), '1234567890', '          '), ']')) = '[ . . ]']/b">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

However, this would mean coding the horrible expression twice, so an alternative approach could be to make use of the `mode` attribute on the template call.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="el[normalize-space(concat('[', translate(translate(normalize-space(text()), ' ', '_'), '1234567890', '          '), ']')) = '[ . . ]']">
        <h3>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="b"/>
        </h3>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b" mode="b">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that in XSLT 2.0, you could use the [matches](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html) function

```
<xsl:template match="el[matches(normalize-space(text()), '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$')]">
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, Tim) You've saved a lot of time for me.